# VSCode extension SFTP does not appear in Activity Bar

Tags: visual-studio-code, plugins, sftp

I use Visual Studio Code V1.79.1 with extension `SFTP` from Satiro Mata with v.1.18.1.
The problem exists also with other extensions.

The installation of the plugin looks ok and it is shown as installed. However the icon is missing in the Activity Bar on the left-hand side. So I can't use it at all.

There is no information about this in the debug console. The only information is a "Not yet activated" in the extension's "Runtime Status" tab.

Can you help?

[image: no icon on activity bar (where the red cross is)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I installed and had a look at that `SFTP` extension and indeed it will not create an Activity Bar icon - **until** the extension is activated.

You can activate the extension by running the command

```
SFTP: Config
```

Then it will create a `sftp.json` file in your `.vscode` directory and the Activity Bar icon will appear.  And the icon will be there whenever you reload vscode.  If you delete the `.vscode/sftp.json` file that will deactivate the extension (on the next reload) and the Activity Bar icon will disappear.

That is just the way the developer created the extension.  As can be seen in the extension's `package.json`:

```json
"activationEvents": [
  "onCommand:sftp.config",
  "workspaceContains:.vscode/sftp.json"
],
```

Comment: Thank you! It looks like in our company this sftp.json could not be created automatically due to write protection. It's solved now.